# How to change a list of multiple images on hover

Tags: javascript, html, hover, onmouseover, onmouseout

I have a list of images and I want to be changed when I hover on it and then change back to the previous image on mouse leave. and each image is different. I have done it but the event is being executed on two images only when the mouse hovers on the first item. and I couldn't figure out the right way.

//html code//

```
      <li>
        <div class="card">
              <img class="my-img" id="my-img1" src="./images/AMH010301_G-1-dresslink.jpg" alt="Denim Jeans">
              <h1>Lorem1</h1>
              <span class="price-first">$24.99</span>
              <span class="price">$17.99</span>
              <br>
              <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
              <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
              <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
              <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
              <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
              <button class="add-to">Add to Cart</button>
        </div>  
       </li>
       <li>
        <div class="card">
              <img class="my-img" id="my-img2" src="./images/AMH010327_W-1-dresslink.jpg" alt="Denim Jeans">
              <h1>Lorem2</h1>
              <span class="price-first">$24.99</span>
              <span class="price">$14.99</span>
              <br>
              <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
              <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
              <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
              <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
              <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
              <a href="product-page.html"><button class="add-to">Add to Cart</button></a>
        </div> 
       </li>
```

//JavaScript//

```
 let img = document.querySelectorAll('.card img');

for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
     img[i].addEventListener('mouseover', hover);
     img[i].addEventListener('mouseout', leave);
}


function hover() {
    document.getElementById("my-img1").src = "./images/AMH010301_G-5-dresslink.jpg";
    document.getElementById("my-img2").src = "./images/AMH010327_W-5-dresslink.jpg";

}

function leave() {

    document.getElementById("my-img1").src = "./images/AMH010301_G-1-dresslink.jpg";
    document.getElementById("my-img2").src = "./images/AMH010327_W-1-dresslink.jpg";

}
```

Comment: Well you hardcoded two images to change on mousever so not sure what the issue is....

Comment: `img[i] = document.querySelector('.my-img').addEventListener('mouseover', hover);` That make no sense

Comment: epascarello. the issue is when I hover on any of these images the event happen on both images which I don't want. I want each event to be executed on the image that I hovered on. so basically when i hover on image one. image two also is being hovered

Comment: You are binding the events to the same exact image on every loop.... `document.querySelector('.my-img')` is selecting the same image. Your code is changing image two! `document.getElementById("my-img2").src = "./images/AMH010327_W-5-dresslink.jpg";` is in the hover code, it does not know it is not supposed to change it for only a certain image.

Comment: epascarello. i just edited the code that actually was my mistake but the issue is still there.

Comment: And the issue is still the same that the function changes all the images.... So you need to add logic to know what image you are on.... And only change that one image, not every single one.

Answer (score 0):

First it seems you are only attaching your event to one of the images and not both. The code below will loop through all of the images and attach event to them.

```
let img = document.querySelectorAll('.card img');
for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++)
{
    img[i].addEventListener('mouseover', hover);
    img[i].addEventListener('mouseout', leave);
}
```

Second the event that you are attaching to the images does not look at which image is being hovered it just changes the images for both of them. The following code will look at the image that you are hovering over and only modify that.

```
function hover(e) { e.target.src = e.target.getAttribute("data-hover-img"); }
function leave(e) { e.target.src = e.target.getAttribute("data-leave-img"); }
```

Finally for each image to have different images to change to and from on and off hover you need to store that information somewhere connected to the image. I chose to go with data attributes as seen above. So the HTML for your images should look like this.

```
<img class="my-img" id="my-img1" src="./images/AMH010301_G-1-dresslink.jpg" data-hover-img=""./images/AMH010301_G-5-dresslink.jpg"" data-leave-img="./images/AMH010301_G-1-dresslink.jpg" alt="Denim Jeans">

<img class="my-img" id="my-img2" src="./images/AMH010327_W-1-dresslink.jpg" data-hover-img="./images/AMH010327_W-5-dresslink.jpg" data-leave-img="./images/AMH010327_W-1-dresslink.jpg" alt="Denim Jeans">
```

Comment: patrickSmith. Thankx Brother it was easy and clean by using attribute but I made it complex.

Comment: No problem! I would look into using jQuery as it will make a lot of what you are doing simpler.

Answer (score 0):

On every iteration you select the same image....

```
document.querySelector('.my-img')  <-- selects first image with the class
```

So you just bound mouseover to the first image multiple times. Now if you fixed the loop to select the correct image, you still would have an issue because your hover code does not look know what image you are hovering and you change all of the images inside of the method.

So you could add in logic into the hover or you could just simplify your code.

So what you want to do is when you hover over an image it changes to a different image. One of the easiest things to do is to use data-attributes and a mouse events.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[data-src2]').forEach(function (img) {
  img.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    if (!img.dataset.src) {  // see if we hovered yet
      img.dataset.src = this.src  // if not set orginal source so we can flip back
    }
    img.src = this.dataset.src2  //set src to second image
  })
  img.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    img.src = this.dataset.src  //set back to orginal
  })
})
```

```html
<img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300" data-src2="https://placekitten.com/g/200/300" />

<img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" data-src2="https://placekitten.com/g/200/200" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you asking how to register the eventlisteners and be able to backtrack which element fired the event? Something like:

```
img[i] = document.querySelector('.my-img').addEventListener('mouseover', function() { theselectedElement=i; hover();});
```

(2 statements- one for the event and another for the element) and then process the events depending on the selected element?